# numpy.ndarray with different lengths

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

The following code produces the following output below.

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import imdb
(trd, trl),(ted,tel)=imdb.load_data(num_words=100)
print("type(trd)")
print(type(trd))
print("trd.shape")
print(trd.shape)
print("trl.shape")
print(trl.shape)
print("ted.shape")
print(ted.shape)
print("tel.shape")
print(tel.shape)
print("trd[0]")
print(trd[0])
print("len(trd[0])")
print(len(trd[0]))
print("trd[1]")
print(trd[1])
print("len(trd[1])")
print(len(trd[1]))
```

produces

```
type(trd)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
trd.shape
(25000,)
trl.shape
(25000,)
ted.shape
(25000,)
tel.shape
(25000,)
trd[0]
[1, 14, 22, 16, 43, 2, 2, 2, 2, 65, 2, 2, 66, 2, 4, 2, 36, 2, 5, 25, 2, 43, 2, 2, 50, 2, 2, 9, 35, 2, 2, 5, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 39, 4, 2, 2, 2, 17, 2, 38, 13, 2, 4, 2, 50, 16, 6, 2, 2, 19, 14, 22, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 22, 71, 87, 12, 16, 43, 2, 38, 76, 15, 13, 2, 4, 22, 17, 2, 17, 12, 16, 2, 18, 2, 5, 62, 2, 12, 8, 2, 8, 2, 5, 4, 2, 2, 16, 2, 66, 2, 33, 4, 2, 12, 16, 38, 2, 5, 25, 2, 51, 36, 2, 48, 25, 2, 33, 6, 22, 12, 2, 28, 77, 52, 5, 14, 2, 16, 82, 2, 8, 4, 2, 2, 2, 15, 2, 4, 2, 7, 2, 5, 2, 36, 71, 43, 2, 2, 26, 2, 2, 46, 7, 4, 2, 2, 13, 2, 88, 4, 2, 15, 2, 98, 32, 2, 56, 26, 2, 6, 2, 2, 18, 4, 2, 22, 21, 2, 2, 26, 2, 5, 2, 30, 2, 18, 51, 36, 28, 2, 92, 25, 2, 4, 2, 65, 16, 38, 2, 88, 12, 16, 2, 5, 16, 2, 2, 2, 32, 15, 16, 2, 19, 2, 32]
len(trd[0])
218
trd[1]
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 78, 2, 5, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 26, 4, 2, 8, 2, 2, 14, 2, 20, 13, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 21, 14, 69, 2, 8, 30, 23, 7, 4, 2, 2, 93, 4, 2, 9, 2, 2, 5, 2, 4, 2, 9, 35, 2, 4, 2, 9, 2, 2, 4, 2, 9, 4, 2, 2, 19, 4, 2, 5, 89, 29, 2, 46, 37, 4, 2, 9, 45, 43, 38, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 26, 2, 5, 2, 11, 2, 2, 4, 2, 9, 2, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 15, 2, 2, 68, 2, 2, 15, 2, 2, 2, 98, 5, 4, 2, 9, 43, 2, 2, 15, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 11, 2, 2, 2, 50, 9, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 18, 2, 32, 2, 2, 14, 9, 6, 2, 78, 22, 2, 64, 2, 9, 8, 2, 2, 23, 4, 2, 15, 16, 4, 2, 5, 28, 6, 52, 2, 2, 33, 89, 78, 2, 16, 2, 95]
len(trd[1])
189
```

This is very strange since despite trd is of numpy.ndarray type, the first element and the second element have different lengths.

Comment: check the `dtype`.  I expect it is `object`

Comment: trd.dtype returns object. But what does it mean?

Comment: `trd` is list like, containing references to python objects, such as these arrays that differ in shape.

Comment: Yes, text dataset typically contains sentences of different length. What's your question?

Comment: I could not create such variables having such attributes as trd to test my understanding. If I can write a few line of codes to confirm then I can claim I understand it. But now I could not.

Comment: A=np.array([[1,2],[],[1,2,3,4]], dtype=object) answers my own question.